# Check the serial number of VGA2USB device from ubuntu command prompt

Tags: 12.04, usb, vga

I have vga2usb device that connected to the ubuntu system. And this system I access online on my ubuntu machine. Now I want to check the serial number of attached `vga2usb device serial number` from ubuntu command prompt. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below command does the job,

```
dmesg
```

Example:

```
[ 9196.128103] usb 1-1.2: Product: Cruzer Glide
[ 9196.128107] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[ 9196.128110] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 200512339104E9136420
[ 9196.203755] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 9196.203866] scsi7 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[ 9196.203985] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[ 9197.205535] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Cruzer Glide     1.26 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
```

To get the exact lines,

```
$ dmesg | awk '/.*Manufacturer: SanDisk.*/ {for(i=1; i<=2; i++) {print; getline}}'
[ 9196.128107] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[ 9196.128110] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 200512339104E9136420
```

To get the exact Serial Number of your connected USB,

```
$ dmesg | awk '/.*Manufacturer: SanDisk.*/ {for(i=1; i<=1; i++) {getline; print $NF;}}'
200512339104E9136420
```

**Note: In the above replace SanDisk with your usb manufacturer name.**